# Ignore object method for istanbul coverage report

Tags: javascript, unit-testing, istanbul

I have a set of unit tests for my web application that run using Mocha and jsdom.  I am using jsdom instead of a real browser in order to have my mocha unit tests run as fast as possible and we will have integration tests that will run selenium that will test more of real browser stuff.  I am also using istanbul to generate code coverage reports however some code can not be tested with Mocha/jsdom.  Take this code for example:

```
var myObject = {
    //...

    /* istanbul ignore next */
    _resizeEvent: function() {
        if(this.props.isActive) {
            //.9 match the scss max-height: 90%, this value needs to be kept in sync with the sass code
            this.getDOMNode().querySelector('.modal__content').style.maxHeight = Math.floor(window.innerHeight * .9) + 'px';
            this.getDOMNode().querySelector('.modal__content').style.maxWidth = Math.floor(window.innerWidth * .9) + 'px';
            this._centerPosition();
        }
    },

    //...
}
```

Since there is no real browser, this method can not really be tested with jsdom.  The issue I am running into is that even though I have the `/* istanbul ignore next */` before the object method, it is still telling me that the code inside the method is not covered (instead of just telling me it is ignored).

Is there an easy way to completely ignore object methods and all of its contents without having to add `/* istanbul ignore next */` before each statement within the method?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The following worked for me:

```
var myObject = {
//...
};

/* istanbul ignore next */
myObject._resizeEvent = function () {
//...
};
```

Comment: Was afraid of that answer, was hoping for a solution while keeping the ability to define object properties with the original object definition.  I guess this is the worst case scenario if I need to be able to ignore these object methods.

Answer (score 1):

Was facing this too, fortunately there's no need for myObject._resizeEvent. You just need to make sure that the ignore next is next to the function name.

The following works:

```
var myObject = {
    _resizeEvent /* istanbul ignore next */: function() {

    },
}
```